# Find Mobile Devices on the network c# web app

Tags: c#, android, ios, networking

I am developing a small web app for the office, what i want to do is scan the local network for staff's mobile phones to see if it is on the network.  If it is not on the network then I will assume they are out and display a currently out notification for that staff member, if I get a response then I will assume they are in.  I need a reliable way to scan for all types of mobile phones.  I have tried arp -a but phones are not showing up.
Ideally I would like to use the MAC address of the phone and then rescan every 10 minutes or so.  I have tried to ping an iPhone but this only works when the phone is actively using the network.

Any idea would be much appreciated.

Comment: I doubt there is a reliable way. Are you even sure that all the staff member connect their phones to your local network every time they come into the office?

Comment: I think this is fundamentally a networking question.  Consider posting on http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/  You solution will depend largely on your network architecture.  If wireless device are on a different subnet (which is likely) MAC addresses and ARP tables won't work for you.  A general solution might be to create a service to ping known addresess and store results in a database.  You could create a web app using the ping results in the database.

Comment: All phones are work phone and they all connect to the network automatically when they come in range of the network.  Wireless devices are on the same subnet mask and do show in a scan when they are active.  Thanks for the tips, will have a look at networkengineering.stackexchange.com